# Don't find node_module file in twig

Tags: twig, node-modules, symfony5

I'm on symfony 5.3.

I want to import a node_modules file in twig.

So I did that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="/node_modules@fancyapps/ui/src/Fancybox/Fancybox.scss">
```

But it isn't find when i load the page. I've tried by add "../" before, but I don't find the solution.

is there a function which allows, in the same way as {{asset ('')}} to go to the public folder, to go to the node_modules folder?
I haven't found anything about it personally.

The error in the console navigator:

```
GET https://localhost:8000/node_modules@fancyapps/ui/src/Fancybox/Fancybox.scss net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yet I searched for hours before asking you, but luckily I found a suitable solution just after.
In fact, it suffices to keep the same line except that instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules_files">` it is necessary to put `<link rel="import" href="node_module_file">`
Thanks anyway! :)